# Why Spring-web did not add javax.javaee-api in its POM?

Tags: java, spring

When I was learning Spring framework, I found a strange compile error:

> "can not find class:javax.servlet.ServletException".

After searching the code, I found some codes in `org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer` class, it uses `javax.servlet.ServletException`:

```java
package org.springframework.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext; //here
import javax.servlet.ServletException;//and here

public interface WebApplicationInitializer {
    void onStartup(ServletContext var1) throws ServletException;
}
```

but, in its POM file, no dependency defined:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  <name>Spring Web</name>
  <description>Spring Web</description>
  <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework</url>
  <organization>
    <name>Spring IO</name>
    <url>https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>jhoeller</id>
      <name>Juergen Hoeller</name>
      <email>jhoeller@pivotal.io</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework</url>
  </scm>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>GitHub</system>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues</url>
  </issueManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I thought every library should write its dependency in its POM file, so that Maven can recognize and auto download the dependent library. **Why Spring-web omit the dependency?**

Answer (score 3):

> Why Spring-web omit the dependency?

Don't know why exactly.  You would have to ask the developers for the complete reasoning ...

If you compare the spring-web 5.0.0 POM file with the latest 4.x.x POM file, you will see there was a major clean-out of the dependencies.   A lot of [cruft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruft) was removed, including any dependency on the servlet api JAR.

If you look at the dependencies for spring-webmvc 5.0.0 (shown [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.RELEASE)) and scroll down to the Provided dependencies, you will see that there is a dependency on "javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api » 4.0.0".   Contrast that with spring-web 5.0.0 (shown [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.0.0.RELEASE)).

Note that spring-web (i.e. the dependency that you using) cannot *need* a dependency on servlet-api for itself, or it wouldn't build.

---

So this leads me to think that maybe *your* project needs to depend on spring-webmvc rather than spring-web ... if you want to pick up a transitive servlet-api dependency.

(Are you reading a text book or following a tutorial or video for an older version of Spring?  If yes, I advise you to either update your textbook or use the older Spring release while you are learning.)

---

And returning to your question:

> Why Spring-web did not add javax.javaee-api in its POM?

One reason is: because it doesn't need it!